# Adding 1 to a binary type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a cdc table that has a binary sequence column and I need to join table on to itself on a column of type binary(10). I have to change its value so it matches the next record so I can return both rows in the data set because an update will be applied with this data.

I need to change `0x0BB636D9239D01000000` to `0x0BB636D9239D01000001` so I can join back to the table and get the data. Problem is I can't just add +1 so I could I add to first binary to make it like the second binary so I can get the next sequential record.

Comment: What do you mean by "add one"? A `binary` value isn't a numerical value, you don't "add" to it.

Comment: What about adding 1 to 0x0BB636D9239D0100000F or 0x0BB636D9239D010000FF?

Comment: Ok, well I need first value to become second value.

Comment: `convert(binary(10), cast(@binaryValue as bigint) + 1)`?

Comment: What and why are you storing as binary anyway?

Comment: @Xedni - `BIGINT` will not work, because it only supports an 8-byte value. (Just adding 1 using implicit conversion to INT, which only supports 4-byte values.)

Comment: SQL Server has no `Int128` equivalent so trying to do this in SQL will be tedious

Comment: Is this a one-time repair across an entire table, or is this an operation that needs to be done on the fly as part of a query? Please supply some context, as this may well be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Xedni you code does not fail but it does not provide right value from: 0x0BB636D9239F00000000  to: 0x000036D9239F00000001. The values are not the same.

Comment: Dale K.. This is not my data I pull data from the source system this is what I am getting. I have no control on how the source system stores its data.

Comment: XY_Problem this is not a one time repair this will be part of an on going pipeline to bring and process data.

Comment: The explanation of the problem doesn't seem clear. If you "need the first value to become the second value" why can't you just assign it? If you just need to replace the `00` on the end with `01` why can't you just `select substring(0x0BB636D9239D01000000, 1, 9) + 0x01`?

Comment: So is this data meant to represent a numerical value? If so why are you not using a numerical data type?

Comment: @ThomA - I presume they are using binary because SQL Server does not have an 80 bit integer.

Comment: I see the question now mentions CDC - I assume you are trying to do something with [`__$seqval`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-capture-instance-ct-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or similar? You should ask an "X" question about how to achieve your aims with CDC. Not a "Y" question about how to increment that value

Comment: Would you have the ability to code & run a CLR routine in your environment?

Comment: The edits to mention CDC makes more sense now, but it highlights that you have a flawed understanding of what the binary(10) value actually is - there's no real world guarantee that `0x0BB636D9239D01000000` is followed by `0x0BB636D9239D01000001` here because these are Log Sequence Numbers. There could be many other DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE operations carried out on other tables in the database (even transaction rollbacks) before a subsequent record gets inserted or updated in the same table as the one that you're looking at, i.e.: there could be a huge gap in the LSNs.

Comment: smells like a classic XY problem ....

Comment: Apart from, @TN, a `numeric`/`decimal` could *easily* store the full range of a int80. The max value of a (signed) int80 is `604462909807314587353087`, which would fit fine in a `numeric(24)`.

Comment: @ThomA - Good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the binary value exceeds the size of SQL Server's largest integer value (BIGINT at 64 bits), you will need to divide the value up and perform a two step add with carry.

```
-- Split
DECLARE @UpperHalf BIGINT = SUBSTRING(@Binary, 1, 5)  -- Upper 5 bytes (40 bits)
DECLARE @LowerHalf BIGINT = SUBSTRING(@Binary, 6, 5)  -- Lower 5 bytes (40 bits)

-- Increment with carry
SET @LowerHalf += 1
SET @UpperHalf += RIGHT_SHIFT(@LowerHalf, 40) -- Carry
SET @LowerHalf &= 0xFFFFFFFFFF -- Trim

-- Combine
DECLARE @Result BINARY(10) =
     CONVERT(BINARY(5), @UpperHalf)
     + CONVERT(BINARY(5), @LowerHalf)
```

This could also be wrapped up in a user defined function:

```
CREATE Function IncrementBinary10(@Binary BINARY(10))
RETURNS BINARY(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Split
    DECLARE @UpperHalf BIGINT = SUBSTRING(@Binary, 1, 5)  -- Upper 5 bytes (40 bits)
    DECLARE @LowerHalf BIGINT = SUBSTRING(@Binary, 6, 5)  -- Lower 5 bytes (40 bits)

    -- Increment with carry
    SET @LowerHalf += 1
    SET @UpperHalf += RIGHT_SHIFT(@LowerHalf, 40) -- Carry
    SET @LowerHalf &= 0xFFFFFFFFFF -- Trim

    -- Combine
    DECLARE @Result BINARY(10) =
         CONVERT(BINARY(5), @UpperHalf)
         + CONVERT(BINARY(5), @LowerHalf)
    RETURN @Result
END
```

Or implemented inline using a series of `CROSS APPLY`s:

```
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CAST(SUBSTRING(D.Binary, 1, 5) AS BIGINT) AS UpperHalf,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(D.Binary, 6, 5) AS BIGINT) AS LowerHalf
) S
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        (S.LowerHalf + 1) & 0xFFFFFFFFFF AS LowerHalfIncremented,
        S.UpperHalf + RIGHT_SHIFT(S.LowerHalf + 1, 40) AS UpperHalfIncremented
) I
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
         CONVERT(BINARY(5), I.UpperHalfIncremented)
             + CONVERT(BINARY(5), I.LowerHalfIncremented)
             AS Result
) R
```

Sample results:

| Binary | FunctionResult | InlineResult |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x0BB636D9239D01000000 | 0x0BB636D9239D01000001 | 0x0BB636D9239D01000001 |
| 0x00000000000000000000 | 0x00000000000000000001 | 0x00000000000000000001 |
| 0x00000000000000000001 | 0x00000000000000000002 | 0x00000000000000000002 |
| 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE | 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF | 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF |
| 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF | 0x00000000000000000000 | 0x00000000000000000000 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GD6pWpcI).

The above uses the bitwise RIGHT_SHIFT() function, which is only available in SQL Server 2022 and later. For earlier versions, an integer divide can be used - `/ 0x10000000000` for a 40 bit right-shift. (Note that our split values do not use all of the BIGINT bits, so we do not need to worry about negative numbers, which would not work with a simple divide.)  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gyQtW-1r).

Comment: T N looks great but I am getting Right_Shift is not a valid command. Do I have to create that function? Or was that a typo

Comment: Your favourite search engine tells you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-shift-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I suspect you need to provide your SQL Server version.

Comment: I am on MSSQL 2019. Yea I just saw your link its for 2022.

Comment: For earlier versions, a bitwise right shift can be accomplished with an integer divide - `/ 0x10000000000` for a 40 bit shift. (Note that our split values do not use all of the BIGINT bits, so we do not need to worry about negative numbers, which would not work with a simple divide.)  See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gyQtW-1r).

Comment: The cross apply still has a Right_shift I can not use that in 2019. How else can I do this in MSSQL 2019. The results it's producing is exactly what I need.

Comment: @LeoTorres - Did you look at the code in the fiddle link in my comment just before yours above?

Comment: @TN yes thank you confirmed this is a working solution for MS SQL 2019